# css bullet in firefox

Tags: css, html

```
<ul>
   <li> test </li>

</ul>
```

by default when view on firefox, the test is shifted to the right hand side? how to made it align to the left ?

Comment: Take a look at setting the padding and margin styles for both the `<ul>` and the `<li>`. elements. How they align can vary a little by browser, but you should be able to work out something that meets your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text is shifted to the right a bit, because there are bullets to the left.

If you would like to remove the bullets, the simplest method is to add:

```
ul.nobullet, ul.nobullet li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

and then just do

```
<ul class="nobullet"> <!-- etc -->
```

Comment: .. +1. In addition to your response, you could perhaps add `text-align: left`?

Answer (score 1):

Use css text-align **attribure** with value **left**. I think that default Firefox is shift text to the left, but look like you change the text-align css attribute somewhere that make it align to the right

```
<ul>
     <li>a</li>
     <li>aaaa aaaaa dddddd</li>
</ul>
<style>
   ul li
    {
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `padding-left` style.

```
<ul style="padding-left:0;">
   <li> test </li>

</ul>
```